# What code language is this?

Tags: programming-languages

I know, silly question, but I am not a programmer and really need to known...

```
to look-for-food
  if food > 0
  [ set color orange + 1
    set food food - 1
    rt 180
    stop ]

  if (chemical >= 0.05) and (chemical < 2)
  [ uphill-chemical ]
end
```

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This language is called [LOGO](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logo_%28programming_language%29).  It's often used with Turtle -- drawing lines on the screen.

Related Anecdote:

My first encounter with a computer was around 1985, in my classroom we had an Apple (Apple ][ probably?).  This was one of the main programs that was available.  I had learned how to do `to` in order to define a subroutine.  I tried it once, but I couldn't remember the syntax for defining the specifics.  And then when I tried to exit the `to` routine definition context, I couldn't remember how to exit it.  The teacher could sense that I was confused, and was coming over to help me.  I figured I'd be in trouble for straying beyond the scope of the exercise that I was supposed to be working on, and figured the teacher wouldn't know how to recover either.  I panicked and powered off the computer.  My first "did you try turning it off and on again?" experience!  :)